# Is there a name for an object with both position and velocity?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

I know of "position vectors" and "velocity vectors". I'm looking for the name of an object which contains both a position vector and velocity vector, if such a name exists?

Comment: A vector in the [Phase space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space)

Comment: yes, if you are considering a 2 dimensional problem

Comment: Classical space $\text{$\pi: $TM}\to M$ the tangent-bundle.
E.g. Abraham/Marsden: Foundations of Mechanics.